# Java - I get NullPointerException in my program

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

My program will run exept on this Exception:

Here's example:

```
case 3:
   //display contact    
   cList.displayContacts();    


 public void displayContacts(){
        int i;
        for(i=0; i < myContacts.length; i++){
            Contact c = myContacts[i];
            System.out.println("Name: " + c.getName());
            System.out.println("Number: " + c.getNumber());
            System.out.println("Email: " + c.getEmail());
            System.out.println("------------------------------------");
        }
    }
```

Exception atlog:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>    at ContactList.displayContacts(ContactList.java:45)
>    at ContactListDriver.main(ContactListDriver.java:67)

Comment: What is line No 45 ?? Show us full code.

Comment: Has `myContacts` been initialised?

Comment: either myContacts is null or one of the entries in myContacts is null. Fix that.

Comment: Okay i'll post the whole code.

Comment: @Abdul Well, you only had to tell what the line 45 is ? is it `for(i=0; i < myContacts.length; i++){` or `System.out.println("Name: " + c.getName());` ?

Comment: awh,, for System.out.println("Name: " + c.getName());

Comment: ok, then it the array `myContacts[i]` which is null, print the variable i and verify why you don't initialize it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the array myContacts cells is not intilized (The defualt value is null), 
that is why a you get a NULL point exception.

Add a null check :

```
Contact c = myContacts[i];

    if (null != c) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Adding a `null` check won't solve the original problem. And `myContacts` can also be null.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously `c` is null. You need to check that your array `myContacts` was initialized in a full range from i = 0 to myContacts.length

*edit*
According to your last comment my guess was correct, some of references in `myContacts[]` array are `null`.

You could print whole array and see which elements are null:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myContacts));
```

Another possibility is that `myContacts` itself is null, so it throws `NPE` earlier, as explained in *T.J. Crowder*'s answer.

Comment: `myContacts` can also be null.

Comment: @ZouZou true, and that is reflected in another answer, I will edit mine

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. This line throws because `myContacts` is `null`, so trying to access `length` on it causes the NPE:

   ```
   for(i=0; i < myContacts.length; i++){
   ```
2. This line throws because `c` is `null`, so trying to access its `getName` method causes the NPE:

   ```
   System.out.println("Name: " + c.getName());
   ```

   That would happen if at least one of the entries in `myContacts` is `null`.

You'll know which by looking to see which is line 45. (That would have been useful information to put in the question!)

You can debug these sorts of things by stepping through the code in a debugger.